# Entity Framework 5 Generated Parametised Sql Sometimes Incorrect For Same LINQ Query

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and Sql Server 2008 R2 (SP1) Standard Edition.

I'm executing some LINQ to Entity Framework code which does something along these lines:

```
public Site GetSite(int siteId)
{
    using (var context = new SystemContext())
    {
            return context.Site.Where(x => x.Id == siteId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Now my understanding is that because siteId above is a variable, it will generate SQL which uses sp_executesql to parametise the siteId.  Now, the majority of the time, it does just this.

However, using SQL profiler, I can see it also very often does this:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[sitename] AS [sitename], 
…truncated fields for sake of clarity 
FROM [dbo].[Site] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[id] = @11
```

Note that it's not using sp_executesql, and it should be.  It's also comparing the site's Id field against '@11'.

11 is the actual value of siteId in the LINQ expression, so it appears to be prefixing it with a @ - you'd expect a generated parameter name to appear here, not the variable's value with this @ prefix.  This is then quite rightly raising a SQL error: Must declare the scalar variable "@11".

This also happens with numerous other LINQ expressions in our system, again, it only sometimes happens though.  Does anyone know what might cause this?  Thanks!